# Openai gym Module not found

Tags: python-3.x, openai-gym

When I run the below code, i got the error Module not found.

```
import gym
import gym_robot   
import numpy as np



env = gym.make('robot-v0')
state_size = env.observation_space.shape[0]
action_size = env.action_space.n
```

Error is ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gym_robot.envs.helper'

I made a github repository https://github.com/zoraiz-ali/gym where anyone check the files.

Answer (score 1):

I've cloned your repo and installed the package doing `pip install .` from the root folder

Then I ran

```
import gym
import gym_robot
import numpy as np



env = gym.make('robot-v0')
state_size = env.observation_space.shape[0]
action_size = env.action_space.n

print(env.observation_space.shape[0])
print(env.action_space.n)
```

Everything worked fine, got `360` and `5` for both prints respectively, could you be more specific on your error ? Did you install the package with pip ?

Comment: thank for your reply. I cloned repository on anaconda prompt using this command "git clone https://github.com/zoraiz-ali/gym.git "                                                                                                              after this I ran (base) C:\Users\ZORAIZ>cd gym                                                                         after this I install package by run this command python setup.py install

Comment: Valentin Macé, can you please tell me, how you install this step by step. Because i got same error again

Comment: Valentin Mace, where you cloned the repository? I means anaconda prompt or anyone else

Comment: I cloned the repository using a standard terminal in my desktop (clone it anywhere it will be fine). Then I cd into gym, I install the package using "pip install ." as mentioned in my anwser, it will install gym-robot 0.3 (or something similar, I don't remember exactly the name) and that's it, it worked for me